# how to store the query result into a variable? mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregate-functions, objectid

```
  let userId = await db.get().collection(collection.ORDER_COLLETION)
  .aggregate([
    {
      $match: {_id:objectId(orderId)}
    },
    {
      $project: {UserId:1,_id:0}
    }
  ]).toArray()
```

//output
[ { UserId: 61c4c7cb8d3b9622509f0c03 } ]

i want to save userId to an variable .
like let a = 61c4c7cb8d3b9622509f0c03

what will i do?

Comment: So whats problem? What did you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aggregation operations process multiple documents and return computed multiple results.

If you wish to get only one user you can limit the aggregation by adding another step

```
{ $limit: 1}
```

And then you can save it into a variable

```
const { userId } = results[0];
```

Or probably in your case, better to use the `findOne` operation

```
const user = db
  .get()
  .collection(collection.ORDER_COLLETION)
  .findOne({ _id: objectId(orderId) });
```

Then you can save the userId into a variable

```
const userId = user._id;
// or you can use object destructuring
const { _id: userId } = user;
```